# How can I import a Python module in a Sublime Text plugin?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'm having trouble making a Sublime Text 3 plugin. I just installed wxPython with Python 2.7 on my Macintosh.

In the terminal, my Mac can find wxPython (`import wx`). But the source code of a Sublime Text plugin cannot import wxPython.

You can check out the screen capture below.

[image: ImportError: No module named 'wx']

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Plugins are executed using Sublime's internal Python interpreter, not any version of Python installed on your computer. Nearly all of the standard library is included, but a few packages (including Tkinter, among others) are not. To my knowledge it is not possible to use `pip`, for example, to install 3rd-party modules into Sublime Text.

However, if you would like to include some 3rd-party code, just put it in your plugin's directory. For example, if you store your plugin code in `Packages/MyPlugin` (where `Packages` is the directory opened by selecting **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`**), and you want to include the 3rd-party library `foobar`, just copy the `foobar` directory into `Packages/MyPlugin`. Then, in your plugin code, use the following template, assuming you're trying to code for both ST3 (Python 3.3) and ST2 (Python 2.6):

```
try: #ST3
    from .foobar import mymodule
except ImportError: #ST2
    from foobar import mymodule
```

Obviously, if you're just planning on supporting ST3 (there are enough differences in the API to make programming for both versions annoying), you won't need the `try`/`except` clause. Also, if you are going to be distributing your plugin via Package Control or some other method, make sure you **can** redistribute the 3rd-party code, and that your license is compatible with its license.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. :) for me It was a big help. thks!!

Comment: To find out where pip installed the module: `pip show <module name>`.

Comment: Does Sublime's Package Control understand Git submodules? i.e. if I add a dependency as a submodule, will it load?